# How to prevent Python derived classes from changing the return type of a base member function?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-typing

Consider this code:

```py
class MyBaseClass():
    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return 42
```

What could I add to my base class such that type linters (mypy, Pylance) raise errors when a derived class redefines the method with different type annotations like below?

```py
class MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass):
    def my_method(self) -> bool: # Expected int
        return True
```

From what I've tried, `@final` prevents a method from being reimplemented completely, instead of preventing classes from being reimplemented.

`Final` from the `typing` package doesn't seem to solve my problem. I naively tried:

```py
class MyBaseClass():
    def my_method(self) -> Final[int]: # pylance: "Final" not allowed in this context
        return 42
```

but `Final` seems only relevant when defining attributes.

Comment: That's just not the Python philosophy.  If some clever person comes up with a use case for your class that expands the possible return values, then there is no legitimate reason why you should prevent that.

Comment: In general they'd already catch that. The specific case of int -> bool they don't because that's a _valid type_, bool is narrower than int so anything that calls the method expecting an int back will be just fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts expanding the possible return values _is_ a bit of a problem, because it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Expanding the possible _parameters_ is OK, as is _narrowing_ the possible return values, because existing callers can still pass what they did before and get what they expect back. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=366dc86be0eed4e89837211f2900a797

Comment: That's a philosophical guideline, not a rule.  The language shouldn't be enforcing that.

Comment: @TimRoberts The language *doesn't* enforce that; tools like `mypy` do. The point of using `mypy` is to write type-safe code, and allowing LSP-breaking definitions makes code potentially type-unsafe.

Comment: there would some overhead, but you could use a library like `pydantic` that enforces typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type hints are not meant to prevent arbitrary changes to your code. They are meant to prevent writing code that is not type-safe. Your specific example *is* type-safe.

---

`mypy` already flags *incompatible* changes to the method type as an error.

```
$ cat tmp.py
class Base:
    def method(self) -> int:
        return 0

class Derived2(Base):
    def method(self) -> str:
        return "foo"
$ mypy tmp.py
tmp.py:6: error: Return type "str" of "method" incompatible with return type "int" in supertype "Base"  [override]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why is this incompatible? Consider the following code:

```
x: Base = Derived2()
n: int = x.method()
```

This should be a static type error, because `Derived2.method` returns a `str` value, not an `int` value. `mypy` prevents this by not allowing `Derived2.method` to have a return type that isn't *consistent* with `int` in the first place.
(Where `a` is considered consistent with `b` if `a` is a subtype of `b`, or if either `a` or `b` is `Any`.)

In your example, there is no error, because the return type of `Derived.method` is consistent with the return type of `Base.method`. The following code is type-safe

```
x: Base = Derived()
n: int = x.method()
```

because the type of `Derived.method` returns a `bool`, which is a subtype of `int`. No matter what value it returns (`True` or `False`), that is a valid `int` that can be assigned to `n`.

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
```

Answer (score -2):

Does this get you any closer?

```
class MyBaseClass():
    @final
    def my_method(self) -> int:
        ret = self._my_method()
        assert type(ret) == int
        return ret

    def _my_method(self) -> int:
        return 42


class MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass):
    def _my_method(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

We have several automated tools to help a team
produce solid code, including

- type checkers, e.g. mypy
- linters
- unit tests
- coverage measurement, e.g. pytest -cov
- .git/hooks/pre-commit
- CI / CD, e.g. jenkins

Any one of those can helpfully "break the build"
so we pay closer attention to a recent commit
or solicit advice from colleagues.

```
>>> type(False).__mro__
(<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>>
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
```

The OP seeks to prevent children classes
from narrowing a return type from `int` to `bool`,
which though "different" is still compatible.
The type system permits such narrowing;
{False, True} are {0, 1}.
So a type checker like mypy wouldn't be
the tool of choice to achieve that policy goal.
There are several tools at your disposal.
Select one that makes sense for your use case.